# Javascript: Iterate through an array to get object property for each element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lookup

I have an array with multiple objects

```
"status": [
    {
      "feature": "sun",
      "color": "yellow",
    },
    {
      "feature": "rain",
      "color": "grey",
    },
```

I want to return the value of the property 'color' for each 'feature'
The output would return: 'yellow' and 'grey'

I don't really know how to start ...

Thanks

---

Comment: As a string (`"yellow grey"`) or as an array (`["yellow","grey"]`)? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < yourObject.status.length; i++)
{
    console.log(yourObject.status[i].color);
}
```

Maybe you should start [at the beginning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) with how loops work?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMüller. I should have been way more clear in my question...sorry.
I am actually trying to return the 'color' based on 'feature'. For example, looping through the element containing 'sun' will return 'yellow'. If status.feature === "rain" return color (and it should return 'grey'

Comment: I still think I am not sure what you want to achieve. If the feature is "rain", you want to return the color? Only in this case?

Comment: for a feature it should return the associated color
I am trying to populate the 2 color values in 2 different sentences based on the feature. So it's a loop with a condition.
if feature = sun, return color (yellow)
if feature = rain, return color (grey)

I am probably not seeing something very obvious ....

Comment: I got it ... it is very obvious.
   for (var i = 0; i < status.length; i++)
{
  if (status[i].feature === "rain")
    return status[i].color;
}

SHame on me ... THanks @DavidMuller!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

`filter` returns an array, so if you're sure that there will only be a 1:1 correlation between feature/color just return the color value of the first element:

```
function getColor(feature) {
  return obj.status.filter(function (el) {
    return el.feature === feature;
  })[0].color;
}

getColor('sun'); // yellow
getColor('rain'); // grey
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3b3p4w8s/)

Comment: I like that idea a lot @Andy! I get 'obj is not defined' though

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var obj = {
    // ...
    "status": [
        {
            "feature": "sun",
            "color": "yellow"
        },
        {
            "feature": "rain",
            "color": "grey"
        }
    ]
    // ...
}

// Array
var r1 = obj.status.map(function(obj) {return obj.color})

// String
var r2 = obj.status.map(function(obj) {return obj.color}).join(' ')

console.log(r1, r2)
```